# I have a nested JSON data

Tags: json

This is My JSON data I am getting data in nested format and I don't have table for that and I want to create database and table for that, Can anyone Explain the JSON data and simplify and also I want to know the structure for that Is it in List and ordered list and also tell me the which all are columns in JSON data.

```
{
 "gstin":"29AAHCS4690J1ZQ",
"fp":"072017",
"b2b":[
  {
     "ctin":"01AAACJ4126D1ZE",
     "cfs":"Y",
     "inv":[
        {
           "itms":[
              {
                 "num":1,
                 "itc":{
                    "tx_cs":0,
                    "elg":"ip",
                    "tx_i":112.5
                 },
                 "itm_det":{
                    "csamt":0,
                    "rt":18,
                    "txval":625,
                    "iamt":112.5
                 }
              }
           ],
           "val":738,
           "inv_typ":"R",
           "flag":"N",
           "updby":"S",
           "pos":"29",
           "idt":"31-07-2017",
           "rchrg":"N",
           "cflag":"U",
           "inum":"FL-17000069",

"chksum":"4d3e41facf5002f418e1ac605d9888d74ee21652e19de6db624fc7106e3c5866"
        }
     ]
  },


  {
     "ctin":"29AACFI3027K1ZC",
     "cfs":"Y",
     "inv":[
        {
           "itms":[
              {
                 "num":1800,
                 "itc":{
                    "elg":"ip",
                    "tx_c":171.59,
                    "tx_s":171.59
                 },
                 "itm_det":{
                    "samt":171.59,
                    "rt":18,
                    "txval":1906.5,
                    "camt":171.59
                 }
              }
           ],
           "val":2250,
           "inv_typ":"R",
           "flag":"N",
           "updby":"S",
           "pos":"29",
           "idt":"06-07-2017",
           "rchrg":"Y",
           "cflag":"U",
           "inum":"0042",

"chksum":"aa1187a2bb7d6098c39c4c992bd391ab7fd59e7eeefcea5b91fc9881ba4423d8"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "ctin":"29AAACT7966R2Z6",
     "cfs":"Y",
     "inv":[
        {
           "itms":[
              {
                 "num":1,
                 "itc":{
                    "elg":"ip",
                    "tx_c":20,
                    "tx_s":20
                 },
                 "itm_det":{
                    "samt":20,
                    "rt":5,
                    "txval":800,
                    "camt":20
                 }
              }
           ],
           "val":800,
           "inv_typ":"R",
           "flag":"N",
           "updby":"S",
           "pos":"29",
           "idt":"06-07-2017",
           "rchrg":"Y",
           "cflag":"U",
           "inum":"507002834",

"chksum":"64b19ecd192545bcfeac89f9ef7e30965122d5159be6a66d4c7888a8b6e1b6ae"
        },
        {
           "itms":[
              {
                 "num":1,
                 "itc":{
                    "elg":"ip",
                    "tx_c":20.38,
                    "tx_s":20.38
                 },
                 "itm_det":{
                    "samt":20.38,
                    "rt":5,
                    "txval":815,
                    "camt":20.38
                 }
              }
           ],
           "val":815,
           "inv_typ":"R",
           "flag":"N",
           "updby":"S",
           "pos":"29",
           "idt":"26-07-2017",
           "rchrg":"Y",
           "cflag":"U",
           "inum":"507015095",

"chksum":"c76544937d5f7b8513bb64d45ba5708ff4f67197652b6ba06a605931b7ce58b6"
        }
     ]
  },

}
```

Comment: The structure of a JSON is the JSON itself, and it does not per se contain concepts as "columns" etc. You can check the validity of a JSON on jsonlint.com, which also is a great tool for outputting JSON in a readable format.

Comment: Look at the indent to see the struture. Every level can be stored by one object

Comment: yeah, but how to insert this in the database.

Comment: You have to map the object structure to a relational structure or just use a ORM. What language will be used? Which database?

Comment: Javascript and PHP, MySQL.

Comment: Ok, look at the json structure and extract the objects. Create a DB table per object. Where objects reference one or more other objects save the ID(s) of the target objects. Maybe there is a easy way in javascript or PHP - I´m not too familiar with both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the json structure and extract the objects. Create a DB table per object. As an example the following json is an array/list of items:

```
"itms":[
      {
         "num":1,
         "itc":{
            "tx_cs":0,
            "elg":"ip",
            "tx_i":112.5
         },
         "itm_det":{
            "csamt":0,
            "rt":18,
            "txval":625,
            "iamt":112.5
         }
      }
   ],
```

Inside it you can find `num` which is the number of items.
Then there are two items `itc` and `itm_det`.

For example `itm_det` has - beside others - a property `iamt` (looks like item amount) and a property `txval`

To make it persistent in a database you would create a table `xyzitem` which consists of columns: `ID`, `csamt`, `rt`, `txval`, `iamt`
Therefore you have to find good types for each column.

Whenever a table has a reference to one other object save the ID of the other row. If there are more objects to reference you´ll need another table between that saves both the ID of the parent object and the ID of one element per row.

I hope you´ll get the point how to solve your problem!

see following link to understand what these objects mean: 
http://www.risersoft.com/gst-nirvana-return-filing/csv-format/gstr2

Comment: should I create a table for itc or no?

Comment: No, itc is just the name / tag for one item. I have no idea what the item is, but it looks like an article. So I would name the table `articles`. Inside this table you have one row (=one entry) for `itc` and one for `itm_det`.        So answer is: No. Instead create a row for `itc`.       This is the difference between object oriented and relational view.

Comment: You are right but further, there are number of items I will update my code see there, please.

Comment: Yes, off course. I just wanted to push you in the right direction to enable you to find the right solution. I will not write your code :) As a hint: Why dont you loop over all item objects and insert each into the DB?

Comment: one more question what is after item_det    "val":738,
           "inv_typ":"R", and so on.

Comment: I have no idea about the objects meaning. you have to gather knowledge about the domain to parse / interpret them in a correct way. Furthermore I see that the `itc` and `itm_det` have different structure. If so (and they have different meaning) they belong to different tables.